# Not able to Athena query CloudTrail Logs from KMS CMK Encrypted S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena, amazon-kms, amazon-cloudtrail

I have created S3 bucket encrypted with KMS CMK and configured CloudTrail Logs to store into that same bucket.
CloudTrail is storing logs in the bucket successfully.
However when I execute `SELECT * FROM cloudtrail_logs` in Athena, it does not return any records in results.

I used below query to create `cloudtrail_logs` table in Athena.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE cloudtrail_logs (
eventversion STRING,
useridentity STRUCT<
               type:STRING,
               principalid:STRING,
               arn:STRING,
               accountid:STRING,
               invokedby:STRING,
               accesskeyid:STRING,
               userName:STRING,
  sessioncontext:STRUCT<
    attributes:STRUCT<
               mfaauthenticated:STRING,
               creationdate:STRING>,
    sessionissuer:STRUCT<  
               type:STRING,
               principalId:STRING,
               arn:STRING, 
               accountId:STRING,
               userName:STRING>,
    ec2RoleDelivery:string,
    webIdFederationData:map<string,string>
  >
>,
eventtime STRING,
eventsource STRING,
eventname STRING,
awsregion STRING,
sourceipaddress STRING,
useragent STRING,
errorcode STRING,
errormessage STRING,
requestparameters STRING,
responseelements STRING,
additionaleventdata STRING,
requestid STRING,
eventid STRING,
resources ARRAY<STRUCT<
               arn:STRING,
               accountid:STRING,
               type:STRING>>,
eventtype STRING,
apiversion STRING,
readonly STRING,
recipientaccountid STRING,
serviceeventdetails STRING,
sharedeventid STRING,
vpcendpointid STRING,
tlsDetails struct<
  tlsVersion:string,
  cipherSuite:string,
  clientProvidedHostHeader:string>
)
PARTITIONED BY (region string, year string, month string, day string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'com.amazon.emr.cloudtrail.CloudTrailInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION 's3://<S3_BUCKET>/AWSLogs/<ACCOUNT_ID>/CloudTrail/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data' = 'true');
```

Am I missing anything ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this issue by creating Athena table using below query:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE cloudtrail_logs (
    eventVersion STRING,
    userIdentity STRUCT<
        type: STRING,
        principalId: STRING,
        arn: STRING,
        accountId: STRING,
        invokedBy: STRING,
        accessKeyId: STRING,
        userName: STRING,
        sessionContext: STRUCT<
            attributes: STRUCT<
                mfaAuthenticated: STRING,
                creationDate: STRING>,
            sessionIssuer: STRUCT<
                type: STRING,
                principalId: STRING,
                arn: STRING,
                accountId: STRING,
                username: STRING>,
            ec2RoleDelivery: STRING,
            webIdFederationData: MAP<STRING,STRING>>>,
    eventTime STRING,
    eventSource STRING,
    eventName STRING,
    awsRegion STRING,
    sourceIpAddress STRING,
    userAgent STRING,
    errorCode STRING,
    errorMessage STRING,
    requestParameters STRING,
    responseElements STRING,
    additionalEventData STRING,
    requestId STRING,
    eventId STRING,
    resources ARRAY<STRUCT<
        arn: STRING,
        accountId: STRING,
        type: STRING>>,
    eventType STRING,
    apiVersion STRING,
    readOnly STRING,
    recipientAccountId STRING,
    serviceEventDetails STRING,
    sharedEventID STRING,
    vpcEndpointId STRING,
    tlsDetails STRUCT<
        tlsVersion: STRING,
        cipherSuite: STRING,
        clientProvidedHostHeader: STRING>
)
COMMENT 'CloudTrail table for bucket'
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'com.amazon.emr.cloudtrail.CloudTrailInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION 's3://<BUCKET_NAME>/AWSLogs/<ACCOUNT_ID>/CloudTrail/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('classification'='cloudtrail');
```